# Integration of Tapster robot with Appium is not working for iOS app

Tags: java, ios, appium, robotics, appium-ios

- I have tried to integrate Tapster Robot with appium for automating iOS app.
- I have followed this links for integration of tapster [Hugs Tapster](https://github.com/hugs/tapsterbot) & [Robots](https://github.com/appium/robots)
- I have successfully achieved the calibration of app, but after that if execute the appium test scripts by enabling robot option in settings i'm not able to execute the scripts. And getting following exception `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: undefined status object`

Comment: Hi Rohith! Which version of Xcode, iOS, iPhone and Appium are you using?  Thank you!

Comment: Anyone have code to calibrate tapster for android devices? Thanks in advance.